# Gallery has stopped

Tags: android, image, camera, crop

I try to implement application that help user to capture photo and crop it or pick image and crop it, the application work successfully in android 4.4 but when try to test it in another device 5.1, Dialog appear after crop image and select save option with the following message `unfortunately gallery has stopped` 
the following code how I start cropping.

```
public void ImageCropFunction() {
    try {
      CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
      CropIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
      CropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
      CropIntent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
      CropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
      startActivityForResult(CropIntent, 1);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

    }
  }
```

and for take picture from camera

```
  public void ClickImageFromCamera() {

    CamIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        "file" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
    uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    CamIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    CamIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(CamIntent, 0);
  }
```

and for pick picture from gallery

```
public void GetImageFromGallery() {

    GalIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(GalIntent, "Select Image From Gallery"), 2);
  }
```

and request run time permission using

```
public void EnableRuntimePermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(StartUp.this,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
      Toast.makeText(StartUp.this, "CAMERA permission allows us to Access CAMERA app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(StartUp.this, new String[]{
          Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
          Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,}, RequestPermissionCode);
    }
  }
```

and for get result of pick image or request permission

```
@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      ImageCropFunction();
    } else if (requestCode == 2) {
      if (data != null) {
        uri = data.getData();
        ImageCropFunction();
      }
    } else if (requestCode == 1) {
      if (data != null) {
        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap bitmap = bundle.getParcelable("data");
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        buttonDetect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
    }
  }
```

Logcat not show any issue after crash happen only show this

```
START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: `catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

    }`? Empty? Put the usual e.printStackTrace() in it and a Toast() where you show e.getMessage() to the user. Now your user and you do not know what is happening.

Comment: `and for get result of pick image or request permission ` You cannot use onActivityResult to obtain a permission. It will not be called if you get one. Implement onRequestPermissionsResult() instead.

Comment: @greenapps for `catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { }` i try it but not showing in issue and toast not appear also.
for get permission i mean check for permission granted or not

Comment: `the application show Gallery has stopped after crop the image` Sorry but i cannot follow you. What is it that you are trying to tell? Please formulate better. Adapt your post.

Comment: @greenapps Dialog appear after crop image and select save with the following message `unfortunately gallery has stopped `

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: @CommonsWare it work successfully in version 4 !

Comment: There are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across thousands of Android device models. None of those models have to have an activity that supports that `Intent` action.

Comment: @CommonsWare. Can be be. But if the Gallery app or Fotos app comes up with new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP"); then i would expect them to be able to handle a crop. Here on Marshmellow Fotos app is choosen and crashes too.

Comment: @greenapps: Since this code will crash on millions upon millions of Android devices that lack an activity for this `Intent`, the code should be rewritten to not rely upon some undocumented and unsupported `Intent`. Also, since this `Intent` is undocumented and unsupported, the behavior of any activity that responds is itself undocumented and unsupported. So, who is to say how it would handle a crop?

Comment: @CommonsWare. Fotos app comes up and the user can adjust the grid until he is done. Only after the Save button appears and is clicked the Fotos app crashes. So we know who to blame i think. On this device the user has two choices to crop. The other one is 'Fotos crop'. This one does the job ok.

Comment: On 4.4.4 the Gallery app lets you crop a picture. Nice grid and so. But at the moment of saving it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Android not have Intent Crop but same devices support crop and other not.
I use [this library](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop) for crop. to solve this issue.